# Retrieve data from QDBusMessage in Qt

Tags: qt, dbus, networkmanager

I'm developing an app which have to implement a WiFi connection mechanism (it'll be a fullscreen touchscreen app). To do that I'm using the DBus to communicate with Network Manager. I managed to successfully make it scan access points and list them in the QTableView. Next thing will be to connect to the chosen wifi network. First thing I do when trying to connect is checking if there is an existing connection to that access point already in the system so I do this:

```
settings = new QDBusInterface("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager", "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings", "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings", dbusConnection, this);
QDBusMessage msg = settings->call("ListConnections");
QDBusArgument arg = msg.arguments().at(0).value<QDBusArgument>();
QList<QDBusObjectPath> pathsList = qdbus_cast<QList<QDBusObjectPath>>(arg);
foreach (QDBusObjectPath p, pathsList) {
    QDBusInterface *conn = new QDBusInterface("org.freedesktop.NetworkManager", p.path(), "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Settings.Connection", dbusConnection);
    QDBusMessage msg = conn->call("GetSettings");
    qDebug() << "Reply: " << msg;
}
```

I receive the message and can read it with qDebug(). The message is in d-bus format: `a{sa{sv}}` as the documentation for Network Manager says. And I have problem to parse it to any usable form. From what I understand, the equivalent Qt classes I should put the data to are:

```
QList<QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QVariant>>>
```

And I think I should do it with the QDBusArgument class but can't figure out how exactly it should be done. Can someone tell me what is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem, it turned out to be quite easy. I created the map object and used >> operator:

```
QDBusArgument arg = args.at(0).value<QDBusArgument>();
QMap<QString, QMap<QString, QVariant>> map;
arg >> map;
```